# Sunflower plot with missing data

Tags: r

it seems that sunflowerplot doesn't work with missing data.

I am trying to write a cleared sunflower plot function, which clears the missing values in the input vectors and informs about the number of missing values for each variable in the legend of the sunflower plot. The code is as follows:

```
      library(gplots)
    CleanedSunflowerPlot <- function(x,y,...){
        m<-sum(is.na(x)) 
        n <- sum(is.na(y)) 
            x <- na.omit(x)
            y <- na.omit(y)
        sunflowerplot(x,y,...)
        smartlegend(x="left", y="top",
        c( paste(m , " missing x values") , paste(n, " missing y values"))) 

    }
```

The error I am getting is "Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ"

I tried many different things but couldn't solve it. Thanks.

Comment: cbind x and y and then remove all rows with missing data

Answer (score 0):

Building on @rawr's suggestion:

```r
x <- c(1,2,NA,4); y <- c(NA, 5, 3, 2)
xy <- cbind(x, y)
xy
#       x  y
# [1,]  1 NA
# [2,]  2  5
# [3,] NA  3
# [4,]  4  2

xy[ !is.na(x) & !is.na(y), ]
#      x y
# [1,] 2 5
# [2,] 4 2

sunflowerplot(xy[, 1], xy[, 2])
```